# mongoDB: perform collection.find() on calculated vales in documents

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I have the following documents in a collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("111e2133c57a1d6111111111"),
    "scores" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2021-03-29T05:00:20.965Z"),
            "test 1 points" : 50,
            "test 2 points" : 10,
            "total possible points" : 100
        }
    ]
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("111e2133c57a1d6111111222"),
    "scores" : [ 
        {
            "date" : ISODate("2021-03-27T05:00:20.965Z"),
            "test 1 points" : 30,
            "test 2 points" : 20,
            "total possible points" : 200
        }
    ]
}
```

If I want to find all the documents which have ("test 1 points" + "test 2 points") / "total possible points" greater than .50, is there a way to do this efficiently with the  MongoDB find() command?

Currently, I am using the inefficient method of looping through each document and performing my calculations, then recording the ObjectId if the calculated value is greater than .50.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/c19Xx9-Ahb-

[$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the scores to get into individual documents, use [$add](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) [$divide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/divide/) with [$gt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) to `validEntry` as true or false.

and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) documents back

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$scores" },
  {
    $addFields: {
      validEntry: {
        $gt: [
          { $divide: [
              { $add: [ "$scores.test 1 points", "$scores.test 2 points" ] },
              "$scores.total possible points"
            ]
          },
        0.5]
      }
    }
  },
  { $match: { validEntry: true } }
])
```

if you want to get the original document back [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) them by `_id` and [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) scores back to the array.

```
  {
    $group: { _id: "_id", scores: { $push: "$scores" } }
  }
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/d8xhOHYV4kn